# where is a woocommerce order placed in wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Where do order and everything in it is stored in the database after it is placed from a WordPress woo-commerce website? To be more precise, how can I get my shipping address without using woocommerce classes like WC_Order class? I mean I need to get that data manually through my custom database queries, but I can't find the order and everything associated with it in my database? I know order is stored in the database as post in the wp-posts table but where is the rest of it i.e shipping address billing address etc etc?

Comment: Check this link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-are-the-woocommerce-orders-stored-in-the-database

Comment: Also better idea is to install the plugin locally and dig in to `WP` database.

Comment: from @Amiya's link"WooCommerce 2.x, orders are stored in the post table, postmeta table, woocommerce_order_items, and woocommerce_order_itemmeta tables. Various parts of an order are stored in different tables"

Answer (score 40):

Orders are a Custom Post Type (CPT), so they are stored in the wp_posts table.  If you search the post_type field for 'shop_order', SQL will retrieve all orders.

Then, you must search the wp_postmeta table for all the records with post_id matching the id of the order post. Among the fields you will then find in the wp_postmeta table will be the entire shipping and billing addresses.

Answer (score 19):

```
select
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as billing_email,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_first_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_last_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_1' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_address_1,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_address_2' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_address_2,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_city' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_city,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_state' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_state,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_postcode' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _billing_postcode,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_first_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_last_name,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_1' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_address_1,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_address_2' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_address_2,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_city' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_city,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_state' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_state,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_postcode' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as _shipping_postcode,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_tax' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_tax,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_paid_date' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as paid_date,
    ( select group_concat( order_item_name separator '|' ) from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID ) as order_items
from
    wp_posts p 
    join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
    join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
where
    post_type = 'shop_order' and
    post_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-07-08' and
    post_status = 'wc-completed' and
    oi.order_item_name = 'Product Name'
group by
    p.ID
```

Source [here](http://codecharismatic.com/sql-script-to-get-all-woocommerce-orders-including-metadata/).

Answer (score 9):

Also the order data will be stored in the woocommerce_order_items and woocommerce_order_itemmeta tables (for WooCommerce > 2.5 I believe) These tables contain things pertaining to the actual product the customer bought.

The shop_order post entries have the post_id which matches order_id in woocommerce_order_items. The order_item_id in woocommerce_order_items matches the order_item_id in woocommerce.order_itemmeta.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that woocommerce orders are a custom post type so they are stored in wp_posts.

WooCommerce orders are "custom post" they are stored in "wp_posts" under "post_type" -> ""shop_order"

if you want to select shop orders with sql query you can do something like below.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'", ARRAY_A );
```

Answer (score 2):

This query should be able to help you. You just need to change the DB prefix for your own DB:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  adolfoma_comoconq_wp470.wpkn_postmeta 
  INNER JOIN 
  adolfoma_comoconq_wp470.wpkn_posts 
  ON adolfoma_comoconq_wp470.wpkn_posts.ID=adolfoma_comoconq_wp470.wpkn_postmeta.post_id 
where adolfoma_comoconq_wp470.wpkn_posts.post_type ="shop_order";
```

I just wrote it and I can see email, billing address, name, purchase amount, etc. I didn't see the exact items and the amount, maybe additional querying is necessary.